# Code compiling but not executing Java

Tags: java

I've written the code below and from what I can guess it should execute correctly but it doesn't and I'm hitting my head against a wall. What I'm trying to do after finding the objects to be added to the temp vector list is to loop through the vector list take each file name and count the number of occurrences of a word. I can get both pieces of code to work seperately but when I put them together the code stops executing after the temp vector list has been filled. Can anyone see from my code below what is stopping the rest of the code from executing?

EDITTED CODE >> I've changed a few things around in the code to format correctly and to remove the duplication but now nothing outputs to the screen. I'm sure it's something simple but I just don't seem to be able to see it.

```
                    for(int m = 0; m < temp.size() && occurCount < wordCount;m++)
                    {
                    File aFile2 = new File(temp.elementAt(m));
                    FileReader aFileReader = new FileReader(aFile2);
                    BufferedReader aBufferReader = new BufferedReader(aFileReader);

                    while((line = aBufferReader.readLine()) != null && occurCount < wordCount)
                    {

                        words  = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");
                        if (line == null)
                            break;
                        else 
                        {
                            for(int k = 0; k < words.length && occurCount < wordCount;k++)
                            {
                                if(words[k].matches(wordToSearch))
                                {
                                    occur++;

                                    q.add(words[k]);

                                }
                                else if(words[k].matches(pattern))
                                {
                                    System.out.println(words[k]);

                                        if(temp.contains(words[k]))
                                            System.out.println("Word already in list");
                                        else
                                        {
                                            temp.add(words[k]); 
                                        }

                                }


                            }
                        }
                        lineFile = "";  


                    }
                    occurCount = occur;
                    occur = 0;
                    aBufferReader.close();
                    searched.add(temp.elementAt(m));
                    occurCount2 += occurCount;
                    //occurCount += occurCount;



                   System.out.println(occurCount);
                   System.out.println(q);
                   System.out.println(temp);
                   System.out.println(searched);
```

Comment: This is a LOT of code. You should try to isolate the problem and attach only the relevant part.

Comment: It seems as if you are adding at least one String to the list, then for each string ion the list you are reading a file and adding all the words in that file to the list which would then for each new word in the list read the file again etc...That may simply mean that your program is taking a long time to execute.

Comment: I thought so too Vincent but it just exits out of the program and doesn't display anything to the console. I tried to rewrite it just using the buffer once but it gives me an infinite loop. That's why I seperated the code into two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                char aChar = 'x';
                for (int i = 0; i <= line.length()-1; i++) 
                {
                    aChar = line.charAt(i);
                    lineFile += aChar;
                }

                words = lineFile.split(" ");
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                lineFile = "";
```

would be the same as:

```
               words = line.split(" ");
```

---

```
                for(int k = 0; k <= words.length - 1;k++)
                {
                    if(words[k].matches(pattern))
                    {
                        System.out.println(words[k]);
                        if(!searched.contains(words[k]))
                        {
                            if(temp.contains(words[k]))
                                System.out.println("Word already in list");
                            else
                            {
                                temp.add(words[k]); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

one would normally use `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` instead of `<= n - 1`.

**You used temp.add, which probably should have been searched.add, as otherwise the outer loop
goes on and on: (`for ... < temp.size()`)**

```
                for (String word : words)
                {
                    if (word.matches(pattern))
                    {
                        System.out.println(word);
                        if (!searched.add(word))
                            System.out.println("Word already in list");
                        }
                    }
```

`add` returns false when the word was already contained in the set.

`words` has to be generic typed like `Set<String>`.

Comment: Thanks Joop, I've made a number of changes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, refactor your code. I mean think about it and try to write it a little bit better. For example the following part

```
line = line.toLowerCase();
char aChar = 'x';
for (int i = 0; i <= line.length()-1; i++) {
    aChar = line.charAt(i);
    lineFile += aChar;
}

words  = lineFile.split(" ");
```

can be rewritten as

```
words = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

And you have the same parts of code written twice - extract them to some methods.

I would guess there is much more of that in your code. When you have it, paste the relevant part here and we'll see...

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I have made a few changes to the code based on your suggestion.